# How to randomly shuffle pictures in visual basic

Tags: vba, random, shuffle, randomized-algorithm

I am trying to create a memory game, but I cannot seem to get the pictures to shuffle around everytime I press start. Does anyone know how to help?

Answer (score -1):

Use [**`Randomize`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/randomize-statement) once at the beginning of your procedure.

> `Randomize` uses number to initialize the `Rnd` function's random-number generator, using the system timer as the new seed value. If `Randomize` is not used, the `Rnd` function (with no arguments) uses the same number as a seed the first time it is called, and thereafter uses the last generated number as a seed value.
>   <sub>([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/randomize-statement))</sub>